# Procedure and Triggers in PHPMYADMIN

Tags: sql, database, database-design, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

Where to create and how to run procedure and triggers in phpmyadmin?
I am able to create and run procedure in MYSQL Console but not in phpmyadmin.
When I am trying to call the procedure created in MYSQL Console, throws me to phpmyadmin home page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the steps:-

```
   1. Open PhpMyAdmin
    2. Select the database which you want to create Procedure
    3. in the right Side you can see the **Routines** click on that you can see the Procedures already created for the availlable database
    4. To create Procedure Click on SQL (TAB) then type your procedure. you then Go, After that you can see the Procedure in **Routines** section
```

Comment: I am doing the same but i think there is some thing wrong with my procedure structure.
it is like:
`Create  PROCEDURE Getstudentname
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM student 
END`

Its showing error.

Comment: DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE Getstudentname() BEGIN SELECT * FROM student; END // DELIMITER ;        Use like this,

Comment: already done with that, its showing error like:

ERROR:Unknown Punctuation String @ 11
MySQL said: 
#1064-You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER // CREATE PROCEDURE Getstudentname() BEGIN SELECT * FROM student' at line 1

Comment: Error is because of some syntax. it saying Unknown Punctuation String @. Please see the query.. the issue is only with Syntax. please check the syntax.